# Defining bounds and if-then statement in Pyomo

Tags: python-3.x, pyomo

I am new to pyomo and linear optimizations. My problem statement is showing below:

A chemical company manufactures three types of chemicals: Chemical A, Chemical B, and Chemical C. During a planning period, the company has a total of: 100hr engineering service, 700hr direct labor, and 4000 lb of costly raw material available for the production. The three chemicals require different hours of engineering service, labor, and amount of costly raw material per batch of final product sold:
Fuel A: 1hr engineering service, 10hr direct labor, 30lb of raw material.
Fuel B: 2hr engineering service, 4hr direct labor, 20lb of raw material.
Fuel C: 1hr engineering service, 5hr direct labor, 10lb of raw material.
The company also offers different discounts when bulk purchases are made. The profit data is shown in the following table:
[image]
For example, if 120 batches of A are sold, the first 40 will earn $10/batch, the next 60 will earn $9/batch, and the remaining will earn $8/batch.
I have to figure out the most profitable figure mix.

I am having two problems here. First, how to set the bounds for the variable? I saw a code but didn't understand the bounds limit here.

model.A40 = Var(within= NonNegativeIntegers,bounds=(0,40))

model.A100 = Var(within= NonNegativeIntegers,bounds=(0,60))

model.A150 = Var(within= NonNegativeIntegers,bounds=(0,50))

model.AMax = Var(within= NonNegativeIntegers,bounds = (0,None))

I thought the bounds should be (0, 40), (40, 100), (100, 150), and (150, None)

Also, how can I write down the constrain since it is an if-then statement?

Please ignore if it is a very naive question. I tried a lot but haven't found any good resources.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of different approaches you might use here....  And this is pretty obviously a H/W problem...  And the "other code" you saw is one approach that appears to reference the portion of A that is between the limits in the table, which makes sense as you want to capture the amount in that cost band explicitly.  So, if you added up `A40`, `A100`, `A150`, and `AMax` you would have the total amount of A produced, right?  And the bounds make sense...